# Codificar un texto a bytes Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo es siguiente problema quisiera codificar un texto a bytes pero no de manera tradicional. Tengo un texto ejemplo:

```py
>>> saludo = 'hola'
"hola"
>>> saludo.encode()
b'hola'
```

No quiero que se vea `b'hola'`. Tengo este otro código

```py
>>> import hashlib

>>> hashlib.sha256("hola".encode()).digest()
b'\xb2!\xd9\xdb\xb0\x83\xa7\xf34(\xd7\xc2\xa3\xc3\x19\x8a\xe9%aMp!\x0e(ql\xca\xa7\xcdM\xdby'
```

Yo sé que no es lo mismo un hash pero no es eso lo que quiero que vean si no que es formato de bytes.
Se preguntarán cual es el interés de ese formato. Si yo guardo con encode se guarda en texto normal no codificado.

Por el contrario, si guardo en ese formato queda algo así:

```py
import hashlib
a = hashlib.sha256("hola".encode()).digest()
>>> with open("uid", 'wb') as file:
>>> ...     file.write(a)
32
```

[image: foto de como se ve en visual studio code]

[image: Foto de el bloc de notas]

Como pueden ver se guarda en un formato mas difícil de entender. Yo se que no es un formato seguro pero me gustaría que quedara así.

Answer (score 3):

El hash es perfectamente seguro. Tan seguro que es **imposible** recuperar el texto original a partir del hash :-) No sé si será esto lo que pretendes...

En cualquier caso, la conversión con `encode()` es perfectamente válida, y lo que se guarda en el fichero sí que son bytes "*codificados*". El problema es que tu editor conoce el código que se ha usado porque es un estándar. Por ello, al abrir un fichero con un editor, de nuevo leerás el texto (porque el editor visualiza los bytes que hay en el fichero como caracteres, ya que a fin de cuentas para eso es un editor).

Estás confundiendo, creo yo, codificar con *cifrar*. Si lo que buscas es alguna forma de que el texto quede ilegible al abrirlo con un editor, estás buscando un cifrado.

Si no te preocupa la seguridad y sólo quieres que no sea fácil de leer, puedes usar métodos simples, como por ejemplo hacer un `xor` entre cada byte del mensaje con un cierto byte elegido por tí (por ejemplo con `0xff`). Eso deja el texto lo bastante ilegible. Por otro lado es trivial deshacer ese "cifrado", ya que basta volver a hacer `xor` con el mismo byte. Por desgracia, incluso si no se conociera qué byte fue el que usaste (o si no se conociera incluso que has usado este método), alguien podría "romper el código" mediante un análisis estadístico de los bytes, pues las letras del alfabeto aparecen en castellano con diferente frecuencia.

Aún así, por si te interesa el método o sólo como curiosidad, sería así:

```
mensaje = 'Esto es una demostración de un cifrado trivial'
msj_bytes = mensaje.encode("utf-8")
cifrado = bytes(b ^ 0xff for b in msj_bytes)
print(cifrado)
```

El resultado es

```
b'\xba\x8c\x8b\x90\xdf\x9a\x8c\xdf\x8a\x91\x9e\xdf\x9b\x9a\x92\x90\x8c\x8b\x8d\x9e\x9c\x96<L\x91\xdf\x9b\x9a\xdf\x8a\x91\xdf\x9c\x96\x99\x8d\x9e\x9b\x90\xdf\x8b\x8d\x96\x89\x96\x9e\x93'
```

que ya podrías guardar en un archivo y al abrir en un editor se vería como basura. Para recuperar el mensaje original, lo dicho, aplicas el mismo xor (que en python es `^`) y decodificas los bytes resultantes a caracteres usando utf8:

```
recuperado = bytes(b ^0xff for b in cifrado)
print(recuperado.decode("utf-8"))
```

Y sale:

```
Esto es una demostración de un cifrado trivial
```

Si quieres cifrados más robustos tendrías que usar bibliotecas criptográficas.

Comment: Gracias de verdad por tu respuesta es justo lo que necesitaba :)

Comment: De nada! Si la respuesta es lo que buscabas puedes marcarla como aceptada.